# How can I debug the Bourne Shell with gdb?

Tags: bash, gdb, tar

I built a toolchain script to prepare a Linux build environment. The script can be found here: https://github.com/mynameismevin/prometheus/blob/toolchain/ptool-make.sh

The script runs perfectly until after the Perl section around line 416. After Perl is done, when it goes to unzip `sed`, it complains with this error:

```
tar (child): sed-4.2.2.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

However, if I run the sections by hand, it completes without errors. If I split the script into `ptool-make1.sh` (which ends at Perl) and `ptool-make2.sh` (which starts at sed) and run them sequentially then they both complete without any issues at all. At this point, I assert the issue isn't with the script, and I would like to debug the shell to see if it's an issue with the shell.

Here are some useful configurations:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
user@ubuntu:~$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
user@ubuntu:~$ ls -lh $(which bash)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 998K Oct  7  2014 /bin/bash
```

I don't think Ubuntu bash comes with debugging symbols, so I would assume I would have to recompile to include those?

How would I use `gdb` to debug the shell when I run a script? Or how would I have the shell log to a file while the script runs so I can open it with `gdb` after it's done? I know how to debug a shell script, I don't want to debug the script, I want to debug the shell.

Edit: It doesn't look like Ubuntu `bash` comes with debugging symbols out of the box. `Reading symbols from bash...(no debugging symbols found)...done.`

Edit: `$PROMETHEUS` is set in my root shell. At the end of Perl `cd ..` results in the same results a `cd $PROMETHEUS/sources/`.

Comment: Debugging sh or bash with gdb for an issue in tar probably isn't the easiest direction to go in. You `cd $PROMETHEUS/sources/`, but don't return up a directory. Is this possibly your issue?

Comment: Take a look at [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara `$PROMETHEUS` is an exported variable in my `.bashrc`.

Comment: To start, I'd add a `pwd` statement right before the `tar jxvf sed-4.2.2.tar.bz2` line to verify the working directory is as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shells come with their own debugging tools. The most simple is running them with `-x` (`bash -x ...script...`) which will print each command after variable expansion but before it is executed. That's usually enough to determine the problem.

For more ideas, see [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

You should also consider to write helper functions to reduce the size of the script to just a few lines. You could move special options to configure or post-build steps into extra files and run them from the helper function if they exist.

Looking at the code, it seems that this line is the culrit:

```
cd $PROMETHEUS/sources/
```

everywhere else, you just use `cd ..`. If `PROMETHEUS` isn't defined (the script doesn't define it, that becomes `cd /sources/` which should also fail but doesn't abort your script. Try

```
cd $PROMETHEUS/sources/ || exit 1
```

instead. Also `#!/bin/bash -u` might be useful (abort on undefined variables).

Lastly, you can use `pushd` and `popd` to navigate the folders.

Comment: Thanks. :) I had previously tried `cd ..` at the end of Perl, but it produced the same result. Also, `$PROMETHEUS` is a global variable set in my shell. I will eventually rewrite it in Python.

Comment: Add `pwd` before the `tar jxvf` line with SED to see in which folder you are; maybe that gives you a hint.